# Playing a gif every x seconds, instead of a constant loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to play a gif every 10 seconds, instead of continuously every time the gif finishes.

```
<div class=mainScreenBox>
    <img id="inviteLogo" src="./assets/Happy_Logo_High_Res.gif" alt="Happy Virus" src="" width="364.166666667">
    <script>
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log($('#inviteLogo').attr('src'))
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#inviteLogo').attr('src', $('#inviteLogo').attr('src'))
            }, 1)
        }, 2000)
    </script>
</div>
```

Currently, I have this. However. As you can probably see, this only plays the gif once. I'm not entirely sure how I can make this play the gif every x seconds?

```
<div class=mainScreenBox>
    <img id="inviteLogo" src="./assets/Happy_Logo_High_Res.gif" alt="Happy Virus" src="" width="364.166666667">
    <script>
        var image = $('#inviteLogo').attr('src')
        setInterval(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#inviteLogo').attr('src', $('#inviteLogo').attr('src'))
            }, 1)
            $('#inviteLogo').attr('src', image)
        }, 2000)
    </script>
</div>
```

I have also tried the above. Saving what the original SRC atr is, and then replacing it with the old one every 2 seconds. But this did not have my desired effect either.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have 2 setInterval... And one is repeating every milliseconds.

```js
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#inviteLogo').attr('src', $('#inviteLogo').attr('src'))
            }, 1) // 1 second == 1000 milliseconds
```

If you have control on the frame of the gif, you can also put a frame fixed for 10sec.

so I thing the best way will be

```html
<div class=mainScreenBox>
    <img id="inviteLogo" src="./assets/Happy_Logo_High_Res.gif" alt="Happy Virus" src="" width="364.166666667">
    <script>
        var image = $('#inviteLogo').attr('src')
        setInterval(function() {
           $('#inviteLogo').attr('src', $('#inviteLogo').attr('src'))
        }, 10000) // 1000 == 1sec
    </script>
</div>
```